# Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main

Tags: java, javafx

I just installed scene builder with Eclipse, but when I create a new JavaFX Project and FXML File, I get the error message

> Error: Could not find or load main class application.Main

Every time I press play. I didn't even touch the auto generated source code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add some code and the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Have a `main` method anywhere?

Comment: @MadProgrammer A main method is not mandatory for invoking a JavaFX application ;)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Maybe, but that's what the error means...

Comment: It's just the original auto generated code. It has a main method and I have no error marks.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Cannot comment unless I see the code and the stacktrace :P

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: He would have to have a main method if he wants to start it with the "play" button in eclipse.

Comment: @Roland I missed Eclipse, you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a build problem.

Go in `Project -> Clean`. Then retry to launch.

If it does not work try to give us more detailed explainations.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because "module-info.java" file is duplicated in the package, or try to copy module-info to the application folder of your project

Comment: please take the time to type real English words, that is _your_ (instead of _ur_)